# iPhone UILabel - non breaking space

Tags: ios, iphone, text, uilabel

Is there a way to use non breaking spaces in UILabel text?

For example, I have label with 2 lines and line breaking mode set to word wrap. The content for this label is read from database, where it's stored as a string. Now sometimes my text in label looks like that:

```
lorem ipsum some text
1
```

but I want to display it like that:

```
lorem ipsum some
text 1
```

so basicly, I need to force non breaking space between 'text' and '1'.

I've found some solution [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/5281-non-breaking-space.html), but I think it could work when the text is entered in source code file. In my case the text is in database.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 59):

Use the no-break space (\u00a0) ex: `@"hello**\u00a0**world!"`

```
post.text = [postText stringByAppendingString: @"1\u00a0hour\u00a0ago."];
```

U+00A0  / no-break space / Common Separator, space

from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Comment: To get this to work in my Localizable.strings file, I had to use all caps: `\U00A0`.

Answer (score 40):

For Swift:

```
let sentence = "Barcelona, Real Madryt, Juventus Turyn, Bayern Monachium"
let sentencewithnbsp = String(map(sentence.generate()) {
    $0 == " " ? "\u{00a0}" : $0
})
```

Comment: It's also possible to use `\u{00a0}` directly in string without using the `map` function – `lorem\u{00a0}ipsum`

Comment: If you use Localizable.strings, the Unicode value should be uppercase: `hello\U00A0world`

Answer (score 21):

In **Swift 4** I had to use all caps: `\U00A0`

Example:

`lorem ipsum some\U00A0text 1`

**Update Feb 2020 from the comments. Thanks to [@corban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613121/corban)**:

> In the Localizable.strings file it still needs to be `\U00A0` - in code
>   you have to use `\u{00a0}`

Comment: In the Localizable.strings file it still needs to be `\U00A0` - in code you have to use `\u{00a0}`.

Comment: It should be: `lorem ipsum some text\u{00a0}1` for swift.
The `\u{00a0}` needs to be between the words you don't want to break.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to get this to work in a .strings file, you can type OPTION + SPACE instead of a regular space.

.strings files are usually UTF-8 encoded, so if you open it in Hex view, you will see "C2 A0" in place of the special space character.

Comment: Thanks for the option+space tip - I didn't know this worked for anything other than new lines!

Answer (score 1):

In Inspector set number of lines for Label as 3 or 4 What ever you require Then the Content will be displayed in multiple lines.

Comment: The number of lines is set to 5. That's not a problem. As you can see the text is displayed anyway in 2 lines, in my first and second example. The problem is that I don't want those separated '1' in another line.

Comment: Then set number of lines as 1 and in "adjust to fit" decrease the font size.

Comment: That's not a good option for me, because I want fixed font sizes (for example, to have the same font size as in other labels, with different texts).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to implement a custom word-wrapping function.

```
// pseudo-code
instring;

get len(instring)
if len > textedit.width*charFontSize
    for (textedit.width*charFontSize ) // cycle through string
        insert `\n` into inString at shortest whitespace
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a simple way to do this with UILabel. Of course one way to achieve the same effect is to manually insert a `"\n"` before "`text"` in your example. Another option is to use a UIWebView with static HTML instead of the UILabel, so you can use an actual `&nbsp`.

Comment: Finally, I've done this by inserting "\n" in my texts. Not exactly what I've tried to do, but anyway, works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Swift extension to fix an orphan in a string by replacing the last space with a non-breaking space:

```
extension String {
    var replacingLastSpace: String {
        if let lastSpace = range(of: " ", options: .backwards, locale: .current) {
            return replacingCharacters(in: lastSpace, with: "\u{00a0}")
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

Although note as of iOS 11, [UILabels solve this problem automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200027/uilabel-wrong-word-wrap-in-ios-11).

Comment: yes if you need to support Android with unbreakable spaces, then use `\u00A0` in the translation and you in Xcode after loading the translation, do `localizedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "u00A0", with: "\u{00a0}")`

Answer (score 0):

If this is not going to happen often, you can do this:

```
NSString *string = @"lorem ipsum some \ntext 1";

label.text = string;
```

You can dynamically generate where you put the \n using character counts, word counts etc...