# UILabel issue with sum

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, uilabel, nsattributedstring

My UILabel has a long text (text is different for different situations and languages, I use AttributedString), it ends with amount. Smth like:

```
This amount will be taken from your account: 12.00 $
```

Label has numberOfLines = 0, so sometimes text looks like

```
This amount will be taken from your account: 12.00 
$
```

And it's very important not to set line break between 12.00 and $, because it looks very bad. Are there any special symbol like 
`&nbsp;` in html, so I can put it between 12.00 and $ ? So the UILabel never put like break between 12 and $?

So what I want is:

```
This amount will be taken from your account: 
12.00 $
```

or

```
This amount will be taken from your account: 12.00 $
```

or

```
This amount will be taken from 
your account: 12.00 $
```

but it should never be like

```
This amount will be taken from your account: 12.00 
$
```

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527494/how-to-calculate-uilabel-width-based-on-text-length

Comment: I don't think this is actually a duplicate because the generic solution to replace space with a non-breaking space is not optimal in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there any special symbol like    in html, so I can put it
>   between 12.00 and $ ?

For this case, you can use the nobreak space character `\u00a0`

**Example:**

```
let text = "This amount will be taken from your account: 12.00\u{00a0}$"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the non-breaking unicode space character, however, what you are doing is wrong.

You should be using `NSNumberFormatter` with style set to `.currency` and `currencyCode` set to `USD`.

That would give you:

1. non breaking space automatically
2. correct formatting for all languages (that is, `$12.00` in English, `$(12.00)` for negative amounts in English, `12.00 US$` in European locales).

Answer (score 0):

*Note that I flag to a duplicated question.*

As mentioned in the [duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105053/iphone-uilabel-non-breaking-space), you need to use the ["No-Break Space" unicode character "\u00a0"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm).

What I want to suggest that you might want to use [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter) for handling the currency character, similar to:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
if let amount = formatter.string(from: 12.0 as NSNumber) {
    print(amount) // $12.00
}
```

Comment: no need to set formatter locale to current locale. That's the default. Also, locale is a struct. you can just `formatter.locale = Locale.current`.

Comment: @Sulthan thank you for your note.

Answer (score -1):

So make sure you haven't set a height constraint on your label, and do this.

```
var value = 12.00
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0
yourLabel.text = "This amount will be taken from your account: \n \(value) $"
```

Comment: Im not sure who down voted and answer and why? At least leave a reason.

Comment: Hello, I think your answer has been down-voted because it's not giving the expected result for the OP. This will *always* let the value and "$" to be on a new line, which is not the case here. To elaborate, what if "This amount will be taken from your account:" was only "taken amount"?