# Label line break not working properly in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have a label which shows the pink area on the screen.[image]  However, the word "gender " is not shown in the top line even if it has enough space. Why is it not showing up in the first line itself? What I need
[image]

```
label.text = @"Do you believe in gender equality";
```

Label 
[image]

Comment: Please show, what you tried...just showing images will not helpful to understand your issue.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I just added lines count to 0 and line break to word wrap.

Comment: We need a [mcve], something that we can copy and paste into a playground, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: when I remove the space between in and gender it completely fills in the label but when i gave the space it is not working. What I need is that the word gender must be in the top line and equality in the bottom line.

Comment: Try label!.sizeToFit()

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200027/uilabel-wrong-word-wrap-in-ios-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UILabel` is working as intended by preventing an [orphaned word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans) so it’s more readable. This was introduced in iOS 11. Apple must disable it for iMessage because they probably intend this behaviour for long articles of text, not text messages.

I've seen fixes including

- call `sizeToFit` on the label after the text has been set
- setting `UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "NSAllowsDefaultLineBreakStrategy") // Using this private tricky shortcut may leads appstore rejection.`

But none of these are working on iOS 13, simulator (Not tested on devices).

---

**Fix**

One tricky solution is - append some spaces or two tabs(`"\t\t"`) to the text and set programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
label.lineBreakStrategy = []
```