# SwiftUI: lineBreakStrategy equivalent

Tags: ios, swiftui, uilabel

Is there something equivalent in SwiftUI as `lineBreakStrategy` that we set for `UILabel`?

Comment: Look at `.truncationMode`

Comment: doesn't work, I have the same issue like this one
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65025926/5271999
and the solution works for me in UIKit, but can't figure out the equivalent with swiftUI

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any I just used an UIKit Label and add it to my custom SwiftUI view.